# Linux -> automatic deletion of files older than 2 days

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service, filesystems

I am trying to write something that runs in the background under linux (ubuntu server). I need a service of some sort that deletes files that are older than 2 days from the files system (own cloud storage folder).

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.  Can you think of a way to rephrase this? What approaches have you tried/considered? What were the issues? "Best way" has a lot of variability...

Comment: running a cron job like `find /your/directory -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;` on a day to day basis could be an option, but I am not sure if quick and dirty applies to the "best" solution category you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find`

```
find topdir -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm {} +
```

Use `cron` to run it periodically.